Avoid Kotlin spec formatting wrap
Given the code:
// meehh
class FooBarSpec : BaseSpec(
    {

// nice
class FooBarSpec : BaseSpec({

I can't pinpoint where on the relation between EditorConfig or Intellij Kotlin formatting style this wrap is happening.
I've tried to isolate these without any success
ij_kotlin_call_parameters_new_line_after_left_paren = false
ij_kotlin_call_parameters_right_paren_on_new_line = false
ij_kotlin_call_parameters_wrap = off

